# What is the difference between basemodel and pydantic_model_creator?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm a beginner in fastapi; I have a question about returning the contents of api functions.

I have knew that `BaseModel` could regulate the input parameters of Api functions;  I used the tortoise orm in fastapi and i used `pydantic_model_creator` function to serializer returning the contents of api functions.

But, recently I saw another use of basemodel; it was used to define  the returning contents of api functions.

example: a function about use model;

base.py：

```py
class UserInfo(BaseModel):
    id : int 
    user_name: str
    age: Optional[int]
    user_type: bool
    nickname: Optional[str]
    user_phone: Optional[str]
    user_email: Optional[str]
    full_name: Optional[str]
    user_status: bool
    header_img: Optional[str]
    sex: int
```

serializer.py:

```py
single_user =  pydantic_model_creator(User, name="single_user", exclude=("password", "remarks", "client_host", "create_time", "update_time",))
```

fuunction.py:

```py
async def user_info(req: Request):
    """
    get current user info
    user_id: int
    """
    user_data = await User.get_or_none(pk=req.state.user_id)
    if not user_data:
        return fail(msg=f"ID{req.state.user_id} is fail!")
    print(user_data.__dict__)
    # return success(msg="user info", data=UserInfo(**user_data.__dict__))
    return await single_user.from_tortoise_orm(user_data)
```

So, I want a suggestion. Which of the two uses is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no winner in your question. The two serve two different purposes.

#### What is a BaseModel?

A `Pydantic BaseModel` is a class that defines how your data looks like and the validation requirements it needs to pass in order to be valid.

For further information see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/

#### What's the use of `pydantic_model_creator`?

`pydantic_model_creator` is a function from the library `tortoise-orm`. It is part of this library and thus thought for being used with it. The goal is to transform the declared `ORM` model into a `pydantic` model that works with other web frameworks (e.g. pydantic models can be used also with django).

#### The big picture: how to use them?

You can use `tortoise-orm` as `ORM` and then declare separately all the single `pydantic` models. This will duplicate the effort required and increase the coupling between the different components of your project. It is thus advisable to use `pydantic_model_creator` to create the input models that your `API` will consume and feed them to the `ORM` (the converse also applies since you'll retrieve data and return it to the user).

The only case in which it would make sense to use `BaseModel` instead of `pydantic_model_creator` is if you need to return a particular set of fields or data structured in a particular way. Though, this should be an exception/rare case and not the norm.

On the other hand, if you're not using `tortoise-orm`, you'll need to write the models (`BaseModel`) yourself or use the tools provided by the `ORM`.